# Response.AddHeader not working in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, response.addheader

I have a problem when I use `Response.AddHeader`. Firefox and Chrome work fine (They show the popup and download the file), but not in IE, where it only opens a blank popup and not do anything like download a file or show a prompt. The popup title is "`-- webpage dialog`".

My code is below:

```
byte[] bRpt = ExportReportYoStream(rptMain, ExportFormatType.Excel);
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Test Document.xls");
Response.BinaryWrite(bRpt);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I have also tried many changes like:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/Save";
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

and many more as I can find on the internet.

Comment: I also found that with Firefox and Chrome it will download without "attachment;" in the filename string. With IE it will not download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay.. this problm solved when i tried for a day and figur it out.

simple, ie not allow using "Response.AddHeader" in a popup page (i tried ie8-10).
i dont know why but works on crome and ff.

if any know why ie behavior like that, i appreciate..

thanks,